# Google Foobar - Please Pass The Coded Message Test Case Failure

Tags: python

### Question

You have L, a list containing some digits (0 to 9). Write a function solution(L) which finds the largest number that can be made from some or all of these digits and is divisible by 3.

If it is not possible to make such a number, return 0 as the solution. L will contain anywhere from 1 to 9 digits.  The same digit may appear multiple times in the list, but each element in the list may only be used once.

### Test Cases

Input:
solution.solution([3, 1, 4, 1])
Output:
4311

Input:
solution.solution([3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9])
Output:
94311

### My code

```py
def sum(L):
    totalSum = 0
    for x in range(len(L)):
        totalSum = totalSum + L[x]
        
    return totalSum 

def listToInteger(L):
    strings = [str(integer) for integer in L ]
    concatString = "".join(strings)
    finalInt = int(concatString)
    return finalInt


def solution(L):  
    
    num = sum(L)
    
    if not num % 3:
        L.sort(reverse=True) # sort list in descending order to create largest number
        return listToInteger(L)
    
    else:
        n = num % 3
        flag = False
       
        
    while not flag: # locate digit causing indivisiblity
        if n in L:
            L.remove(n)
            L.sort(reverse=True)
            return listToInteger(L)

        elif(n > num):
            return 0
           
        else:
            n += 3
```

I get the two test cases correct, but there is one hidden case that keeps failing. I'm not sure if the input is not strict enough, or if there is a fault in my logic

the only fault in logic I can think of is if the input was [8,5,3] , the sum would be 16 and 16 % 3 = 1

so it would check the list for 1, 4, 7, 10, 13 , 16 but it wouldnt be in the list so it wouldn't remove 8 or 5. it would return 0 when it should actually return [3].

I added a function for this but even then it was still failing the hidden test case. . .

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: `I added a function for this `  Please add that function code to your question to make it complete. You've already found a problem with your code and tried to fix it but not posted the complete code? Hard to answer then.

Comment: I got simple logic, I think it might works. The code does't work for  [8,5,3]. But there is 3 should return, try to write one more function for finding all combinations of that kinf of lists and you can get when evaluates each list ....Example:  [8,5,3] can be [[8,5],[8,3],[8],[5],[3]] , When you evaluate to find any sub list sum can be divisible by 3, so here [3] can be returned

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to assume that there can only be one digit that is wrong. What would you do with input like `1,1,3`?  sum is 5, n is 2 and you'll try to remove 2, 5, and then fail and return 0.

You need to change your assumptions and check other digits too, and make it possible to remove more than 1 digit when working toward a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked fine for [8,5,3]

example: [8,5,3,6]

sum will be 22

sum%3 will be 1

so numbers need to check in list to delet are 1,4 7,10,13,16,19,22 and it will never delet any elements,since there are no these elements in the list

so still there are 6 and 3 which can be multilple of 3.

so  take 3 and 6 in a list and sort them and answer will be 63

```
def sum(L):
    totalSum = 0
    for x in range(len(L)):
        totalSum = totalSum + L[x]
    
    return totalSum 

def listToInteger(L):
    strings = [str(integer) for integer in L ]
    concatString = "".join(strings)
    finalInt = int(concatString)
    return finalInt

def solution(L):
    num = sum(L)
    if not num % 3:
        L.sort(reverse=True) # sort list in descending order to create largest number
        return listToInteger(L)

else:
    n = num % 3
    flag = False  
while not flag: # locate digit causing indivisiblity
    if n in L:
        L.remove(n)
        L.sort(reverse=True)
        return listToInteger(L)
    elif(n > num):
        k=[]
        for i in L:
            if i%3==0:
                k.append(i)
        if len(k)!=0:
            k.sort(reverse=True)
            return listToInteger(k)
        else:
            return 0
       
    else:
        n += 3

l=[8,5,3]
print(solution(l))
```